# When to use "andare a" vs "andare al, allo, alla, ai, agli, alle" vs "andare in"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, latin

I'm trying to understand the rules but I don't seem to find a proper pattern.

The main problem is my Spanish and French conflict with Italian...

Io voglio andare a USA?
Io voglio andare ai USA?
Io voglio andare in USA?

In Spanish I would use a, in French I would use aux, which is ai... but what about Italian?

Comment: 'Io voglio andare *negli* USA' is the correct construct.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider Without the pronoun *io*, of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The preposition you must use in sentences with the structure

> "andare" or "stare" + name of country, state, continent, region or big island

is ***in***. For instance:

> - Mi piacerebbe andare **in** Liguria.
> - Quest'estate andremo **in** Francia.
> - Voglio andare in campeggio **in** Corsica.
> - Sei stato **in** Africa?

However, if such names are in plural or if they are followed by a specification (e.g. an adjective), you must use the so-called "preposizioni articolate", that is, ***nel***, ***nello***, ***nell'***, ***nella***, ***nei***, ***negli***, ***nelle***. For instance:

> - Non sono mai stato **nella** Francia meridionale.
> - Voglio andare **negli** Stati Uniti.

Note that with the name of cities or small islands, you must use the preposition ***a***. For instance:

> - Vado **a** Firenze.
> - Andiamo **a** Capri.

Source: Fedrica Colombo, *Grammatica e pratica della lingua italiana per studenti stranieri* (edizioni ELI, 2006).

Comment: Anche "Non sono mai stato *in* Francia meridionale" è valida però.