# "Nell'Unione Sovietica" oppure "in Unione Sovietica"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, prepositions, articles

Come si deve dire: "nell'Unione Sovietica" oppure "in Unione Sovietica"? Dato che la forma corretta è "negli Stati Uniti" e non "in Stati Uniti", tendo a pensare che anche in questo caso si debba usare la preposizione articolata. Una ricerca su Google di "in Unione Sovietica" però mostra un gran numero di risultati.

Ad esempio, quale tra queste due frasi sarebbe corretta?

> - Dmitrij Šostakovič raggiunse la fama come compositore *nell'* Unione Sovietica.
> - Dmitrij Šostakovič raggiunse la fama come compositore *in* Unione Sovietica.

Comment: Related: http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/2055/in-belgio-oppure-nel-belgio.

Comment: Ngram mostra l'uso di entrambe le preposizioni  con riferimento all'Unione Sovietica, https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+Unione+Sovietica%2Cnell%27Unione+Sovietica&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20Unione%20Sovietica%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnell%27Unione%20Sovietica%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Sempre dimentico che l'uso dell'articolo determinativo femminile apostrofato (l') davanti a parole che iniziano con la lettera "u" è diverso dal catalano.

Comment: Secondo me, questo caso è un po' diverso di quello del Belgio perché "Unione" sembra essere seguita da una precisazione, "Sovietica" (http://italian.stackexchange.com/q/3639/707).

Comment: E penso che si dica "nella Catalogna del Nord" (https://books.google.es/books?id=5hWJ5rb2oDkC&pg=PA198&lpg=PA198&dq=%22nella+Catalogna+del+Nord%22&source=bl&ots=xnFnqgFbMz&sig=l2IGxFhkGFC2tntX-grVhrzPIb4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EHpgVarZJoTkUZLjgegE&ved=0CBkQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22nella%20Catalogna%20del%20Nord%22&f=false).

Comment: Vedo che Wikipedia usa entrambe le forme: http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unione_Sovietica#Legislazione_su_matrimonio.2C_aborto.2C_eutanasia_e_omosessualit.C3.A0, http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unione_Sovietica#Cultura.

Comment: @Charo Io direi "in Catalogna del Nord”.

Comment: Mi piacerebbe sapere qual è la ragione del voto negativo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

L'andamento della diffusione relativa di “nell'Unione Sovietica” e di “in Unione Sovietica”, quale lo rappresenta (grazie Josh61!) [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+Unione+Sovietica%2Cnell%27Unione+Sovietica&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20Unione%20Sovietica%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnell%27Unione%20Sovietica%3B%2Cc0) (potrebbe essere necessario cliccare su “Search lots...”) di Google Books, sembra privilegiare in un primo momento una netta prevalenza della preposizione articolata, fin verso gli anni Sessanta, nel corso dei quali questa forma tende a declinare mentre guadagna terreno la preposizione semplice.

Ipotizzo che finché il nome della nazione era relativamente “nuovo”, era sentito etimologicamente: si parlava effettivamente di un'unione di un certo tipo, così come in altri tempi si parla della Triplice Alleanza, della Società delle nazioni e così via.

Col passare del tempo, sembrerebbe che lo si sia considerato sempre più un normale nome (come “Francia” o “America”) e quindi usato con la preposizione semplice.

Questo è più uno spunto che altro e lo inserisco come risposta quasi solo per avere lo spazio per esporlo per bene. È chiaro che ci sono vari possibili controesempi (uno per tutti “Regno Unito”, in cui però forse l'articolo ha resistito grazie al suo uso minoritario rispetto agli impropri “Gran Bretagna” e “Inghilterra”).

Comment: +1. Cf.: "nell'Unione Europea" - "in Unione europea" ([Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+Unione+europea%2Cnell%27Unione+europea&year_start=1940&year_end=2010&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20Unione%20europea%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnell%27Unione%20europea%3B%2Cc0))

Comment: È interessante vedere l'evoluzione della lingua.

Answer (score 1):

Che io sappia, la forma corretta (o perlomeno quella di uso comune) è "nell'Unione Sovietica". Posso affermare con certezza di non aver mai sentito nemmeno la forma "in USA", al contrario è molto popolare dire "in Arabia Saudita".
Ciò fa ipotizzare l'assenza di una rigida regola ufficiale per queste espressioni  che, al contrario, sono determinate prevalentemente in base all'uso comune.
Probabilmente questa ambiguità si è generata nel momento in cui sostantivi di uso quotidiano, come "stati" e "unione", sono diventati parte del nome di alcuni Paesi. A sostegno di questa tesi, si pensi all'espressione "in Stati Uniti": la pronuncia (e la lettura) risultano decisamente disturbanti!

Comment: Vedo che Wikipedia italiana usa entrambe le forme: http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unione_Sovietica#Legislazione_su_matrimonio.2C_aborto.2C_eutanasia_e_omosessualit.C3.A0, http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unione_Sovietica#Cultura.

Answer (score 1):

Credo non c'è nulla da chiedersi al riguardo, né il presupposto della domanda—atteso che 'Stati Uniti' è plurale, ma 'Unione Sovietica' no—appare fondato.

Occorre dire 'nell'Unione Sovietica' quando s'intende evocare un'idea che eccede il mero dato geografico, sennò si usa 'in':

> Timošenko nacque nell'Unione Sovietica di Stalin.
>
> Timošenko nacque in Unione Sovietica nel 1952.

Sopra, nel primo caso, si intende circostanziare un particolare contesto storico, mentre nel secondo caso no.

Ciò, peraltro, è vero in genere:

> Oggi viviamo nell'Italia dei balocchi.
>
> Sono nata in Italia il 12 gennaio 1986.

Anche qui, nel primo caso, si intende evocare un'idea che è solo marginalmente—se non per nulla—geografica.

Comment: Come ha detto @DaG, si usa però "nel Regno Unito" e non "in Regno Unito" (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+Regno+Unito%2Cnel+Regno+Unito&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20Regno%20Unito%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnel%20Regno%20Unito%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Immagino però che questa sia la visione d'oggi: come ha detto DaG, attualmente si tende a usare la forma "in Unione Sovietica". (+1 per questa ragione: penso che la risposta sia molto ben spiegata.)

Comment: @Charo Il Regno Unito conserva un'idea estremamente evocativa, tant'è che 2 italiani su 3 non sanno neanche precisamente da quali stati sia formato, di talché c'è un deficit culturale che, di fatto, impedisce di individuarlo quale luogo geografico.